# How to share code across multiple repository with Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, code-reuse

Over time, I developed a variety of utility functions, classes and controls that I reuse across multiple projects. For each of those projects I have a Mercurial repository and I copy the re-usable projects. Obviously this is bad since if I fix a bug in one of the reusable components, I have to copy the code manually in all repository and I could make a mistake in the process.

How do you handle such situation? How to share code across multiple repository with Mercurial in such way that if I do an update in one repository, I can easily integrate with the others.

Comment: I put all my utility functions into one package, and if I wrote new ones for specific projects, I'll migrate that into the utility package when I felt it qualifies as being "stable".

Answer (score 3):

Check out subrepositories: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

They won't help you keep the other copies up to date (you'll have to do that manually), but they will make that easy (you'd use `hg pull; hg update` in the subrepo, then commit the parent repo).

Another option (which I use on a different project) is to mandate a layout, then simply assume that the "utilities" repository is stored at `../utils`, relative to each "real" repository.

Comment: +1 But don't forget that.. _This is considered a feature of last resort._ :)

Comment: @Lipis: Completely off topic, but I really hate those notices they've put on features. Subrepos and Largefiles in particular aren't "features of last resort". They're required for a particular type of problem. Yes, they shouldn't be used all the time, only when necessary, but they're not a *last resort*.

Comment: @PaulS totally agree with you.. I just didn't expect to see that in the official documentation.. and thought it was funny..;) They make sense, but once you know what you're doing Subrepos are pretty cool...